# Is std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to the [cppreference documentation on `std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution),

> The effect is undefined if [`IntType`] is not one of: `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

I'm not sure of how this applies to `std::size_t` - namely with these 3 confusions:

1. On one hand, `std::size_t`, as far as I know, is usually a `typedef` of one of the `unsigned` types in that list.
2. However, I'm not sure if the standard mandates that always be the case.
3. I'm not sure if *"undefined if [`IntType`] is not one of: ..."* implies `IntType` has to nominally match something from that list (the type has to explicitly be one of those, by name) or whether it can structurally match (so a typedef to one of those is considered acceptable as well).

Is `std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>` undefined behavior?

Comment: If you are uncertain, how about `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned> || std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned long> || std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned long long>);`. If it fails on any compiler (what I doubt) it would trigger...

Comment: *Is `std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>` undefined behavior?* It is **defined behavior** on every platform where `std::size_t` is a typedef for one of these: short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long.  On the other platforms, it is **undefined behavior**.  I'm not aware of any platform that has a `std::size_t` that isn't one of those.

Comment: To look at this from a different perspective - if you accidentally run into some platform where `size_t` is not one of the standard types, what are the odds that the rest of your program will work? This is similar to "What happens if `int` is 23 bits?" The standard says that it **can** be..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On one hand, std::size_t, as far as I know, is usually a typedef of one of the unsigned types in that list.

Yes, usually.

> However, I'm not sure if the standard mandates that always be the case.

No, it can technically also be `unsigned char` or an implementation-defined extended unsigned integer type. The former seems extremely unlikely to me to ever make sense and I don't know any example of the latter either.

> I'm not sure if "undefined if [IntType] is not one of: ..." implies IntType has to nominally match something from that list (the type has to explicitly be one of those, by name) or whether it can structurally match (so a typedef to one of those is considered acceptable as well).

It means that the type named by the template argument shall be one of the ones listed. How it is named is not relevant. A template can not detect that anyway.

---

In practice `std::size_t` will normally be one of `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`. So you can use a simple `static_assert` to make sure that you are not being compiled on some exotic platform that needs extra considerations, as suggested by @Sheff'sCat in the comments under the question:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned> || std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned long> || std::is_same_v<std::size_t, unsigned long long>);
```